# Sending an image to client and opening in new window or tab using MVC 5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

Simple question, but I'm a little confused. In my application, when a user clicks an image's thumbnail, the thumbnail's ID is sent over to this controller action via AJAX:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetHiResImage(string thumbnailID)
{
    Guid id = new Guid(thumbnailID);
    try
    {
        using (var db = new ImagesDbContext())
        {
            var image = db.Images.Where(x => x.ImageID == id).Select(x => x).Single();
            return File(image.ImageData, image.ImageMimeType);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return Json("An error occurred while trying to retrieve the image from the database.");
}
```

Using this code, the client appears to receive the image but nothing happens.

I'd like to return the full-sized image to the client - without redirecting or refreshing the page - but I can't figure out how to do this.  Ideally, I'd like the image to appear in a new window or tab, and I'm trying to figure out which type of `FileResult` (e.g. `FileResult`, `FileStreamResult`, or `FileContentResult`) would be used to do this.

One of the bigger problems is that the image is that the image isn't saved in any directory on the server, so I can't simply return a `FilePath` to the client.

I tried using `return File` and `return FileContentResult` to no avail.  I also thought that I could maybe return a string containing a Base64String representation of the image back to the client and displaying it in a modal dialog, but this isn't ideal because the size of the image might exceed the length/width of the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad candidate for AJAX. Although, you technically can return the image data as the AJAX response, you'd have to do something with it: namely, use the File API in JavaScript to create an image *on page*. That last part is key and why AJAX is particularly unsuited for what you're trying to achieve: you can't open a new tab or window with that image. You can only use it on the current page.

The good news is that you're actually making this far more difficult than it needs to be anyways. Just create a standard HTML link around your thumbnail image and set the href to the URL for this action with the id of the image. Then add the attribute `target="_blank"` to the link, and you'll get a new tab/window with the full-sized image.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetHiResImage", "YourController", new { thumbnailID = yourID })" target="_blank>
    <img ... />
</a>
```

Change your action to return the image data with proper mime-type and your done.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate the help.  Using this method, would I still use `return File` is the Controller action?

Comment: Yes, all you're doing with this action is essentially mimicking a request for an image. If I were to request an actual image on the filesystem like "foo.jpg", what happens is IIS reads the file and sends the data down to the client with the "image/jpeg" mime-type so the client knows to handle it as a jpeg image. Your action would just do the same thing: get the file data and write it to the response and return that response with the proper mime-type.